# Stopping an executable jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have an executable jar file. Once started the only way to stop it is to go to the task manager and end the javaw process. Is there a cleaner way to stop it, say with an UI which a novice user can use?

Comment: Do you have access to the code or is this a third party application?

Comment: I made the whole application, so yeah I have access to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control the code, you want to have something in the GUI that will allow for exiting using `System.exit`.  So, if you were using Swing, you could do something like:

```
JButton b = new JButton("Exit");
b.setActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem with this is that there is no GUI application where I can put a button. I could make another GUI application to stop my jar but this GUI would be working on a different jvm so it might not be able to interface with the other application.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful technique is to listen for windowClosing, which happens when the user clicks the X button on Windows (and the equivalent on other systems):

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

I usually put that in the constructor of the class that extends Frame for the application.

If you are using a JFrame, you also need to add this line:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Or you could just do `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` and avoid the extra `WindowListener`.

Comment: Well the problem with this is that there is no GUI application where I can put a button. I could make another GUI application to stop my jar but this GUI would be working on a different jvm so it might not be able to interface with the other application.

Comment: True, but sometimes you need to do some cleanup that you would not have control over that way.

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not have a GUI - for example if its a service - then you can use local network access to simulate the standard IPC (InterProcess Communication) mechanisms that the operating system normally uses to start and stop services.

A very popular implementation of that you can find in Apache's Commons Daemon project: http://commons.apache.org/daemon/

Comment: I used launch4J to wrap up my jar into an exe, however I WANT it to work as a service, I tried Java Service Wrapper but it doesn't work for me for some reason. I'll look into your link. But as of now my application is not a service.

Comment: Whether or not it is a service, if there is no user interface then the best way to control it is through local network access. Open a listening socket that only accepts connections from the local machine, and wait for commands to arrive in a separate thread.

Comment: Commons Daemon already implemented that for you - they provide both the "server" and "client" for that methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will end when all non-daemon threads have ended.  A way to do this, would be to make all threads but one daemons, and let the last thread be the one that awaits the signal to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my problem. Since I don't have a GUI which I can close, nor do I have a console. The best way is to use the SystemTray API in the java.awt package. Just right click on the icon and exit.